# Apache2 virtual host in a VM, trouble accessing from host machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, virtualbox, virtualhost, hosts-file

I installed a fresh TurnKey LAMP VM (Ubuntu, Apache2, PHP 5.2, the usual) in VirtualBox (latest). I configured networking so it has an IP of `192.168.1.111` on the bridged network. Then I logged into Webmin from the host machine at `http://192.168.1.111/`--worked fine. In Webmin I set up an Apache2 virtual host with the `ServerName` `foo.local` and set up a PHP app in the configured directory. Then I added the line `127.0.1.1 foo.local` to `/etc/hosts`.

Now back in my host machine--Windows 7--I edited my `C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` file and added the line `192.168.1.111 foo.local`. Now, from Windows I can `ssh jordan@foo.local` just fine, and when I `lynx http://foo.local/` from the VM it loads home page of the virtual host perfectly, and the app works perfectly.

But when I open a browser on the Windows host and navigate to `http://foo.local/` I get unexpected results: In IE8 (not my browser of choice, for the record) when I hit `http://foo.local/` it takes me to the VM's Webmin home page, i.e. the same thing as if I went to `http://192.168.1.111/` on the host machine. In Chrome, however, I just get redirected to `http://localhost/`--i.e. Windows' localhost, which doesn't have a web server configured, so error.

Can anybody help me resolve this? I've tried every combination of configurations on both the host and in the VM that I can think of and it's driving me batty. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow finally resolved this. Like I said, tried every configuration I could think of, but in the end it was changing `<VirtualHost foo.local:80>` in `foo.local.conf` to `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

I still don't know why Chrome is misbehaving--some sort of caching issue, probably--but it's working in at least one browser on the host machine, so I'm happy.

Comment: Ah yes it should be `<VirtualHost *:80>` and then `ServerName foo.local` within the `<VirtualHost>` block. Sorry I assumed that was already that way :)

Comment: *:80 tells apache to do Name Based Vhosting - the other option is IP Based Vhosting and by having foo.local set to 127.0.0.1 in your servers hosts file that would have become `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` which is an IP Based VHost. That is why it was working on the server but not over the network.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, c10k. Probably I should have posted the .conf file for good measure; I'm not sure if it was Webmin's mistake or my own, but it doesn't much matter anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting chrome to ensure it has picked up the modified hosts file?

Another option is:

- Go to the Wrench icon
- Options
- Under the Hood
- Clear browsing data
- Turn off all check boxes other than Empty the cache.
- Click Clear browsing data

Comment: Thanks. I have done all of those things with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your Apache config file, I know CentOS/RHEL have it commented out by default.